# Hibernate allow foreign key to be one of many classes?

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I'm trying to implement ***hashtag*** functionality in my database, allowing me to assign a hashtag to different classes. Is it possible to have the foreign key inside the tags class, be one of many different classes (Article, Video, Image)? This would mean having a discriminator column.

E.g

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tags")
public class Tags {
    private String tagName; // the hashtag name; E.g cool-photo
    private <Article, Video, Photo> relatedObject; 
    private String type; // Can either be Article, Video, Photo
}
```

In this example I'd be able to run a simple query:

```
select t.* from tags t where type = 'article' and tagName = 'tag-searching-for' 
INNER JOIN Article a ON t.relatedObject = a.articleId;
```

This would return a bunch of `<type-requested>` objects for the type requested (in this case, articles)!

Is there a built in way of doing this with Hibernate or will I have to build my own solution (which Im happy to do, I'd rather check to see if theres a concret one first).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways, where you can just use a *super entity* - inheritance.

1. create `Taggable`, a new super entity for Article, Video, ...

   ```
   @Entity
   public class Tag 
   {
       private String tagName; // the hashtag name; E.g cool-photo

       @ManyToMany
       @JoinTable(...)
       private Set<Taggable> relatedObjects = new LinkedHashSet<>(); 
   }

   @Entity
   @Inheritance(...)
   public abstract class Taggable
   {
       @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "relatedObjects")
       protected Set<Tag> tags = new LinkedHashSet<>();
   }

   @Entity
   public class Article extends Taggable 
   {
       ...
   }
   ```
2. make `Tag` a super entity

   ```
   @Entity
   @Inheritance(...)
   public abstract class Tag 
   {
       protected String tagName; // the hashtag name; E.g cool-photo
   }

   @Entity
   public class ArticleTag extends Tag
   {
       @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tags")
       private Set<Article> articles = new LinkedHashSet<>();
   }

   @Entity
   public class Article
   {
       @ManyToMany
       @JoinTable(...)
       private Set<ArticleTag> tags = new LinkedHashSet<>();
   }
   ```

In both cases the query you probably will use more often (conversely to the one you brought in example) is something like [JPQL style - not SQL!]:

```
select a 
from Article a
    join a.tags t
where t.tagName = 'tag-searching-for'
```

to get all articles with that specific tagName.

IMHO the first one requires less refactoring and less boilerplate code, but, due to java single-class inheritance limitation, could cause some problem if/when you'll extend your model in the future.

As a side note, I don't see the meaning in using a single `relatedObject`, so I changed it to a `Set<>`

Comment: I think I like the second option better!